# How to get the exact string within the brackets in mysql

Tags: mysql

In my mysql table a field values are as follows:

```
    table name - "clients"                        
    field name - "accent"   
    values are - "Eastern(Northern,Southern),Scottish(East Coast)"
                 "Eastern(South,North,Southern),Scottish(East Coast)"
```

If I give
`select accent from clients where accent like '%north%'`

if more than 100 records not in the same order. Strings with in the brackets are not in the same order means.

It will give above two values. 
How should i get only second value?

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select accent from clients where accent like '%North,%'
```

**Update:**

If you want to select only North not Northern then try this

```
select accent from clients where accent like '%North%' and accent not like '%Northern%'
```

If you want only Northern value then try this

```
select accent from clients where accent like '%Northern%'
```

hope this solves your problem.

Comment: if the value is  "Eastern(South,North),Scottish(East Coast)" like this some times, at that time.

Comment: provide all the possible cases so i can provide you a solution.

Comment: Sorry this is first time, if more than 100 records not in the same order. Strings with in the brackets are not in the same order means

Comment: Ok so you want to select only North Value not Northern.is it right?

Comment: if i give north means it should give north value. If northern means northern like that only for south and southern, etc.

Comment: ok for that i updated my answer,check that for north and northern and same would be case for south and sourthern. However if you want only northern then it should be like this `select accent from clients where accent like '%Northern%'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select accent from clients where accent regexp 'North[^a-z]'
```

The regex means match all that contains 'North' and its not followed by other letters

Answer (score 0):

You can use offset attribute.

```
select accent from clients where accent like '%north%' limit 1 offset 1
```

where limit means you will retrieve only one record and offset means starting from second item.

Comment: Sorry iam not mentioned this. Thank you, It works for two records but if more than 100 records not in the same order. Strings with in the brackets are not in the same order means.